# How to handle N812 lowercase 'ugettext_lazy' imported as non lowercase '_' of pep8-naming

Tags: python, django, pep8

It is very common to import 'ugettext_lazy' as '_'. New version of pep8-naming does not like this. How to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Using the underscore is very common in many projects. One way to get around the warning is to add a comment in that line with # NOQA to instruct the linter to ignore that line.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _  # NOQA
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb If you are using pycodestyle this might be an option. Is it possible to configure the naming conventions like this too, as this kind of feature is supported by pycodestyle through plugins?